# Accessing unique json array

Tags: python

I'm aware the code won't work because I can't work out how to access each array, i.e. `Person-Ryan` and `Personal-Luke`.
There will be multiple and each will be unique and won't know what they be called beforehand.

I would like to print the name on each one in a loop.

JSON:

```
"entities": {
    "Person-Ryan": {
        "name":"Ryan"
    },
    "Person-Luke": {
        "name": "Luke"
   }
}
```

Code:

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
res_json = response.json()

for inner_dict in res_json:
    Test = inner_dict['name']
    print (Test)
```

Comment: `for inner_dict in res_json['entities'].values():`?

Comment: Is the name of the key always "Person...." ? Because if that is the case you can get all the key values inside the entities key and start by checking if the key starts with "Person" or not. The problem with what you did (I assume because this is not very detailed) is that your "inner_dict" variable would be the equivalent of "entities" key. So you need to get the keys inside the res_json['entities'].keys(). This would return ["Person-Ryan", "Person-Luke"]. At this point is when you should check if the key starts with "Person" (if that is required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is just calling `items` function on the dictionary that you get from `response.json()`:

```py
for key, value in res_json["entities"].items():
  print(value["name"])
```

##### Output

```
Ryan
Luke
```

Comment: The keys aren't needed, so `for value in res_json["entities"].values():` would be more succinct and to the point.